# model and readonly attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Is it possible in MVC 3 to set a ReadOnly Attribute to true or false on Model depending of a property in the same class?

maybe something like :

```
 ReadOnly((yyy)?false:true)
 public double? xxx { get; set; }
```

I need to do it in the model or in the controller.

My idea is to block the instruction Html.EditorFor(o=>o.xxx) in the view

Answer (score 0):

Edit: After reading your edit, I think you'd have to create your own custom annotation for that.

I don't know if it works with annotation but you could define your `set` to act that way:

```
public double? xxx
{
    get;
    set
    {
        if(otherAttribute == someValue)
        {
            xxx = value;
        }
        else
        {
            // maybe log it, do other stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, read your edited question. Such information is always helpful to have.